# Search all stored procedure using a #temp table name?

Tags: sql-server

I have many stored procedures in my database and it's difficult to find where the `#myTemp` table has been used.

Is there any query to search a text in all stored procedures?

For example:

```
select... 
where text like '%myTemp%'
```

I want to find a below Sql query in which stored procedure has been used.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  
      [ProcInstID], 
      "Process Name" AS Workflow, 
      "Source", 
      CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN ("Receipt Date" <> ''1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'' AND "Receipt Date" IS NOT NULL) THEN "Receipt Date" END, 101) AS  ReceiptDate 
INTO 
    #MyTempTable
FROM
(SELECT [ProcInstID......
```

Comment: Grab SQL Search from redgate. It is 100% free and an exceptional tool for this kind of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select from [sys.sql_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql)

```
select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as ObjectName
from sys.sql_modules
WHERE Definition like '%myTemp%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to only search stored procedures you can use below query

```
select obj.name, mo.definition
from sys.sql_modules mo
    inner join sys.objects obj on obj.object_id = mo.object_id
where type = 'P' and definition like '%#myTemp%'
```

Comment: Or use `sys.procedures` instead of `sys.objects` and having to specify `obj.type = 'P'` .....

Comment: Thanks to all, I have used above queries its working fine with other table name but not found with  #temptable. Its looks like some where it was hard coded.

Comment: below parameters are using. using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = sqlCmdtimout;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WorkflowStatus"

Comment: Is there a way to search stored procedure using Parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct object_name(id) 
from syscomments 
where text like '%[ABD]%'
order by object_name(id)
```